# How to debug metal kernel of ios in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, shader, metal

I have written metal kernel (.metal) in shader language. But it's not working as I expected so I thought about debugging and I am following [Metal Tips and Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html) for debugging. I have called the `insertDebugCaptureBoundary` method of `MTLCommandQueue` to inform Xcode about debugging.

But still not able to debug GPU part of code like we do in CPU. While doing step debugging in CPU part of code how I will be get prompted to GPU code(.metal file) ? Is it possible to debug the step by step code of GPU ?

If I am asking something meaningless please tell me how to do debugging of GPU code(.metal file) in Xcode  ?

Thanks for reading....

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you, unfortunately I can't find a way to do this and I'm not sure if it's possible as (as far as I'm aware) we don't have as much step by step control of the GPU as we do on the CPU. My current workaround is to simply rewrite sections of code to run on the CPU so values can be logged and inspected. Also I'm not sure why it's down voted so I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the build to use a recent iOS target version and set the Metal compiler options to include source code. Open "Build Settings" -> "Metal Compiler - Build Options" - "Produce Debugging Information".

More information here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_authoring/developing_and_debugging_metal_shaders